# How to add Razor view in MVC 3 after upgrade from MVC 2 hardcoded?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC 2 project which I am trying to upgrade to MVC 3 but using tool I got the error that SLN file are invalid even it's fine and work for me.

so I Upgrade them manually, It means

In sln file change the keys and change the config file in views and in main directory and remove the MVC 2 dll and add the MVC 3 dll.

now my project convert to MVC 3 but a little problem  I fond that when I am trying to add a views I am unable to find the option, It's only show me aspx in the New Window. I need MVC 3 razor based views & layout.

how I can get razor in the menu (add new View option)

Comment: Did you update your Visual Studio?

Comment: I have SP1 and i am sure that the project built before MVC3 maybe in sp1 beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do a bit more with the project file. check out this post, similar problem: [ASP.NET MVC3, Enable Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157445/asp-net-mvc3-enable-razor/5157587#5157587)

---

to paraphrase:

I fixed this by changing the ProjectTypeGuids element in the .csproj file to the following:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

I can now choose either Razor or ASPX as my view engine.

---

see if that fixes your issue.

Personally I'd create a new MVC3 project and copy over the controllers and views and work on them as I need to.

Remember though if you create a new razor view you will need to remove your existing aspx or ascx view as there are checked for first before cshtml (razor).